# Cannot ssh into virtualbox centos from mac os x catalina

Tags: centos, ssh, mac-osx, virtualbox

I have virtualbox installed on a Mac OS X Catalina host.
I have got the Centos 9 guest os running on virtual box.
For centos, i have used NAT in networking options, and mapped 2222 to 22.
I cannot ssh from the mac os to the centos.
Also i note that both host and guest have same ip in ifconfig.
But this seems to be not a problem for the demo i am trying to replicate
(Puppet course on udemy)

Already tried:
Started sshd on the guest os

```
sudo systemctl start sshd
```

Added ssh  to firewall

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=ssh
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Added PermitRootLogin yes to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Restarted: `sudo systemctl restart ssh`

Enabled remote login in the Mac OS x

ssh command goes like this in verbose mode:

```
ssh -vvv osboxes@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 127.0.0.1 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/mansnitz/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/mansnitz/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mansnitz/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mansnitz/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mansnitz/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mansnitz/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mansnitz/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/mansnitz/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mansnitz/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mansnitz/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: I'm quite sure your CentOS 9 VM doesn't have 127.0.0.1 as an IP address. Please try to use the IP of the VM with SSH.

Comment: @vautee the ifconfig shows that IP. Pls see screenshot: https://imgur.com/qFqvOZw

Comment: There should (read: needs to be) also be an IP address bound to the enp0s3 interface. Without that, you cannot continue.